# Shouldn't the matplotlib tag have python syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Can we force questions that are tagged [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) and [pylab](/questions/tagged/pylab) to have the  [python](/questions/tagged/python) syntax-highlighting? Since matplotlib/pylab is a python-only library I don't see why this would be a problem. I've been adding the python tag as a workaround, but this seems like a useless edit. Example:

[Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/matplotlib-save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-so-can-be-used-in-b/9890599#9890599)

Comment: You could simply add a `<!-- language: lang-py -->` in front of your code block to get the highlighting to work.

Comment: @Bart: or better yet, add the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree, but the OP already stated that he did so, but found it a useless edit.

Comment: Eh... Good tagging is never *useless*.

Comment: Not my words and no disagreement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these already have the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag, which should suffice. The 340 that don't:

- [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib+-python)
- [pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pylab+-python+-matplotlib)

...probably *should* have it, if they contain actual code. **Hint, hint.**

That said, there's no harm in enabling the default (auto-detect) formatting for these, since that's what's configured already for [python](/questions/tagged/python). So I've gone ahead and enabled it.